# VB Issues Using Bind With Pipe

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6, upgrade, vb6-migration

I have some VB6 code that I am trying to convert over to .NET, in the code the bind part of the pipe code is throwing an error. Here is the code:

```
With Pipe
        .RemoteHost = "127.0.0.1"
        .RemotePort = CInt("12346")
        .LocalPort = CInt("12345")
        .Bind(.LocalPort)
End With
```

The error that is being thrown is

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Bind' accepts this number of arguments.

I am confused, since this code worked in VB6 and .Bind has the argument of .LocalPort

Can someone please tell me how you would do this in .NET?

Comment: You need to tell us what Pipe is. Obviously, it's networking related somehow, but what datatype is it? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: @RemyPorter The data type is string

Comment: @nate What is the `Type` of `Pipe`? `Dim t As Type = Pipe.GetType()`

Comment: Make sure you have `Option Strict On` in you VB project.

Comment: @MattWilko I did change strict from off to on. However that didn't fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up not needing to use this code. Since I couldn't figure out how to get the code to work in .NET, I just commented the code out. I ran and tested the app, and there wasn't any issues. I didn't create the app, so I am not sure why or how that code was being used anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your LocalPort is an integer type, and the Bind method expects a string.  VB6 would silently coerce the integer to a string for you.  VB.NET does not.  Try changing it to `.Bind(.LocalPort.ToString())` and that should work.  I did VB6 back in the day, but never VB.NET -- so YMMV.

Comment: They data type is already a string, so setting .tostring wouldn't do anything (even though I have seen that work to fix compiler errors). I tried anyway just see what would happen, and I receive the same error.

Comment: How is it a string? you are assigning it as an Integer with: .LocalPort = CInt("12345")

Comment: VB6's Winsock.Bind method expects a Long (LocalPort), and an optional String (LocalIP).